# What's the set up database on Heroku?

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I have deployed my Rails 3.1 app with the MySQL database to Heroku and there everything works fine. I mean, into database are saved the chars right (seems to be used UTF charset on a databases on Heroku).

But when I will run the command `heroku db:pull` (this command will download a whole database from Heroku into the database on localhost), so the downloaded data stored in databased have bad coding - a chars are displayed bad (it looks like my local MySQL database have a different set up of charset than the MySQL on Heorku).

Could anyone give me a tip, how I can find the set up of charset used on Heroku database and how to use it on my local MySQL database?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which MySql add-on are you using?  Heroku uses Postgres by default.

Comment: This one: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Comment: I mean which add-on are you using to provide your MySQL database?  Are you using Xeround, ClearDB or Amazon RDS?

Comment: Well, tell the truth - I don't know. When I want to deploy my app to web, so I just run the command `heroku run rake db:migrate` - this will copy my DB schema from localhost to heroku and then I will run just `heroku db:push(or pull)` - that's all what I do usually. Is here anything important, what I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

All is not lost - you really don't have to use PostgreSQL if you don't want to.

If your database is small enough (which it will have to be since the Heroku PostGres DB is also 5Mb) and you would prefer to remain on mySQL then you could use the ClearDB mySQL addon - http://addons.heroku.com/cleardb - their entry level DB is free and is the same size as the Heroku Shared PostGres DB that you get by default but be careful that the number of connections is limited so don't be going crazy with your web dyno counts.

Once you add the addon if you look at the output of `heroku config` then you can use the DATABASE_URL to create a connection in your favourite mySQL administration tool locally to restore/backup etc data to ClearDB. You may even find heroku db:push would work but personally I've not tried that so would be guessing.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I wanted to add that even though ClearDB offers a free tier, you need to have a verified credit card to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Heroku does not use a MySQL database in production, but a PostgreSQL database.

Therefore you will run into all sorts of issues pulling and pushing data from a different database engine.  Taps is an activerecord based process that will reduce this problem but not all the time.

Ideally you want to use PostgresSQL on your development machine (install via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for simplicity on OSX) and you'll not see any more of these problems.

Alternatively, use one of the MySQL addons as described in the comments in the question.

Comment: ok, but this mean I have to install PostrgeSQL and use it instead of MySQL? Doesn't exist any simple fix for the problematic chars (the count of these chars is 3, maybe 4)?

Comment: Ideally you should use Postgres locally, or a MySQL addon on Heroku (which will cost) to resolve these problems.